# How to detect empty lines while reading from istream object in C++?

Tags: c++, string, input, stream, istream

How can I detect if a line is empty?

I have:

```
1
2
3
4

5
```

I'm reading this with istream r
so:

```
int n;
r >> n
```

I want to know when I reach the space between 4 and 5.
I tried reading as char and using .peek() to detect \n but this detects the \n that goes after number 1 . The translation of the above input is: 1\n2\n3\n4\n\n5\n if I'm correct...

Since I'm going to manipulate the ints I rather read them as ints than using getline and then converting to int...

Comment: ¤ Read each line into a `std::string` by using `std::getline`. Check the string length. Use e.g. a `std::istringstream` to read individual items from the line of input. This will also help you with erroneous input. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Okay you don't have to be rude. At least I tried different ways before posting this. I just wanted to know if there was another way.I'm just learning c++ atm.
Thanks for the istringstream comment though, I'm going to try that mixed with the getline! You can post it as answer if you want, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istringstream is("1\n2\n3\n4\n\n5\n");
    string s;
    while (getline(is, s))
    {
        if (s.empty())
        {
            cout << "Empty line." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            istringstream tmp(s);
            int n;
            tmp >> n;
            cout << n << ' ';
        }
    }
    cout << "Done." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 Empty line.
5 Done.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do need to know about empty line because input is divided by blocks separated by that blank space. And I need to know what data goes to what block.

Comment: @bb2 : In that case I would definitely use `std::getline` to read each line as a `string`. Then you can create temporary `istringstream` based on that string and read from it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I've just noticed that solution was also recommended by Alf P. Steinbach in comment to your question.

Comment: **Fail**: You are reporting an extra empty line. Doing this `while (is.good())` is practically always wrong and definitely wrong here. Use `while(getline(is, s))`

Comment: @LokiAstari: You are right, it's much better. Thank you, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you really don't want using getline, this code works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x;
    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Number: " << x << endl;

        char c1 = cin.get();
        char c2 = cin.peek();

        if (c2 == '\n')
        {
            cout << "There is a line" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But be aware that this is not portable. When you using system that has different end lines characters than '\n' then would be problem. Consider reading whole lines and then extract data from it.

Comment: It's not true that this is non-portable. The newline char(s) of the system is converted to and from '\n'.