# Detecting empty line from text file

Tags: c++, file-io, newline

I have text file like this:

```
7
a

bkjb
c


dea
```

`hash_table` is an array such that `line no.-2=index of hash_table array` that is every line corresponds to an element in array. The element may be empty line or character like `"a\n"` which will like this in text file:

```
a
//empty line
```

First number is used to decide the size an array `hash_table`.
THe << operator is not treating empty line or '\n' char as string and hence not adding into array.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235296/how-to-detect-empty-lines-while-reading-from-istream-object-in-c) but no use . [Here](http://codepad.org/MjRS3fI9) is my try:

```
ifstream codes ("d:\\test3.txt"); //my text file

void create_table(int size, string hash_table[]) //creating array
{   string a;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i=i+1)
        {
        codes>>a;
        char c=codes.get();

        if(codes.peek()=='\n')
            {char b=codes.peek();
            a=a+string(1,b);
            }
        hash_table[i]=a;
        a.clear();
        }
}

void print(int size, string hash_table[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i=i+1)
        {if(!hash_table[i].empty())
            {cout<<"hash_table["<<i<<"]="<<hash_table[i]<<endl;} 
        }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    codes>>size;
    string hash_table[size];
    create_table(size, hash_table);
    print(size, hash_table);



}
```

NOTE: there can be any no. of empty lines with random sequence.

Comment: [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::string::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty).

Comment: no. of chars in line are not fixed

Comment: Note I linked to the `std::string` version, **not** `std::istream::getline` (which should be used rarely to never).

Comment: So your code will be something like `for (; std::getline(file, line); ++lineCount) { if(!line.empty()) table[lineCount]=line; }`.

Comment: I want to include empty line into array. the why `if(!line.empty()) table[lineCount]=line;`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing other things at the same time and not concentrating. The "detecting empty line" in the title made me think that we needed to check that. In which case, if you are including every line sequentially by line number, why aren't you using a `std:vector`?

Comment: well, how vector can help me to do that?

Comment: You are not being very clear. Detect what? Do you want to store every single line (regardless of if it is blank), and store them indexed by line number? So use a `vector`.

Comment: I want want to store every single line (regardless of if it is blank)

Comment: So why are you bothering with a hash map rather than a `vector`?

Comment: its an homework. I have to do it with arrays. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::getline()` instead of `std::ifstream::operator >>()`. The `>>` operator will skip over whitespace, including newlines.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(codes, line)) {
    //...do something with line
}
```

Comment: when does this while loop terminates. It should not add EOF to array.

Comment: @Nikhil It won't. This is the *correct* way to read every line from a file. If you are ever checking the `eof()` function you are almost certainly doing it wrong. This condition will stop when it tries to read past the last line.

Comment: @BoBTFish I did like this [click here](http://codepad.org/HcfqMnaC) but still not working. Compiler stops working without giving any error. See the create_table() fucntion

Comment: works when I delete `hash_table[i]=a;` works fine when I replace it with `cout a;`

Comment: @Nikhil: your code sample makes a C-style array of strings and calls it a hash table. What the error is about is the fact that you make it a C-style array with a size that is not known at compile time. Use a std::vector<std::string> and use .push_back to add new items to the vector.